# c# Random string without duplicate in list of object

Tags: c#

I am trying to grab a random string id from a list of objects when this method is called then remove that id from the list so i wont get a duplicate of that id when i call the method again. I know how to do it with a list of strings, but i dont know how you do it when you have objects in a list.

I try doing something like this, but it does not work.

```
public string RandomHotelID ()
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        string Id;
        foreach(Hotels hotel in LHotels)
        {
            int findex = gen.Next(0, LHotels.Count);
            Id = hotel.HotelId[findex];

        }

        return Id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the foreach loop, and here's why:

```
//Pseudocode of what you want
i <- generate random number between 0 and the number of Hotels
return the hotel id string of the hotel at i
```

Notice, no looping involved.

Code that does that (note, I construct the Random as a private instance variable to avoid randomness problems):

```
class RandomHotelId {
    Random r = new Random();
    public string RandomHotelID ()
    {
        return LHotels[r.next(0, LHotels.Count)].HotelId;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would modify this to avoid getting duplicate id's?

Comment: You could keep track of ids already retrieved in some sort of collection, and do `while (nextValue not in collection) nextValue <- get a different value`

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the checkmark. If you think its well written or useful, you can also upvote